# normal duration time for output caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm going to use output caching for my web pages . pages are almost static . and I want to set cache duration for 24 hours . but I wonder if keeping cached versions of page for 24 hours has any bad effect on server .

what is a good and normal duration for caching output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the content is rarely updated, 24 hours caching period would be fine. Infact you can also set up triggers, so that if the data changes at the source, the cache would be automatically updated.

To set a SQL dependency see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx

To set a File dependency see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67z4z916.aspx

Comment: You post that quote at the end as though it was not you who wrote it. That's pretty disingenuous.

Answer (score -1):

24hs is not a good option i think 5min is a suitable value

Comment: 5 min ? why ? is not it so short ?